# Meteor script loading with data attributes

Tags: cordova, meteor, ionic-framework, meteoric

I have this

```
<script 
src="https://cdn.plaid.com/connect/stable/connect-initialize.js" 
data-client-name="Client Name" 
data-form-id="plaidForm" 
data-key="public_key" 
data-product="auth" 
data-env="tartan" 
data-webhook="/webhook" 
/>
```

How do I turn this into a working, cross-browser script in one Meteor template?

I have it working in Chrome by loading it like this in the template.js rendered function, but it doesn't load right on a mobile device when I use Ionic. I have no idea why, but I'm trying to go to the simplest answer first (maybe Ionic doesn't recognize my javascript code)...

Any help is appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.async = "async";
        script.src = "https://cdn.plaid.com/connect/stable/connect-initialize.js";
        script.setAttribute("data-client-name", "Client Name");
        script.setAttribute("data-form-id", "plaidForm");
        script.setAttribute("data-key", Meteor.settings.public.plaid.public_key);
        script.setAttribute("data-product", "auth");
        script.setAttribute("data-env", "tartan");
        script.setAttribute("data-webhook", "https://e39f6d752a20d470.a.passageway.io/hookthe/plaid");
        $("head").append(script);
    });
```

Here is the line from my browser inspection of this running on the Android simulator.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://cdn.plaid.com/connect/stable/connect-initialize.js?_=1429320699573
```

Comment: Did you ever get this worked out?

Comment: No. Plaid plans to release several updates over the next few weeks including a better way to setup the script. I've put this aside while I wait for some of those.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this answer is a bit late, but Link should have no trouble working with Meteor. The 404 is odd too because I can access that URL directly in my browser.

Were you ever able to sort this out? If you are still having issues with Meteor, I'd suggest trying Link's [custom initializers](https://github.com/plaid/link#step-2-custom-integration) which does not rely on "data-" attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that Link is working in your browser, but not in your Ionic app. I built an Ionic app last week with Link and it worked without issue, so I'm thinking there is something going wrong on your end.

In your Ionic app: are you using AngularJS + UIrouter? What I think might be happening is that you're loading the Link `<script>` tag inside of an `ng-template` script tag - which doesn't work (a script inside of a script is never executed). I might recommend that you try using the [custom initializer](https://github.com/plaid/link#step-2-custom-integration) to avoid this problem, inside of your Angular Controller.

```
plaidApp.controller('BillsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

 var linkHandler = Plaid.create({
   env: 'tartan',
   clientName: 'Client Name',
   key: 'test_key',
   product: 'auth',
   onSuccess: handleOnSuccess,
 });

 function handleOnSuccess(token) {
   $http.post('/authenticate/', {
     public_token: token
   }).success(function(res) {
   }).error(function(err) {
   })
 }

});
```

And somewhere in your `index.html` file include the Plaid script tag

```
<script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>
```

If that doesn't work, you can [create a new issue in our github page](https://github.com/plaid/link/issues/new) so that we can better respond to your issue.